# See entire output of process in 'screen'

Tags: gnu-screen

I am running a script in screen, which takes several days to run. Occasionally, I log back in to check the output, and I'd like to see the output during the times I did not have the screen attached. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `screen` has a scroll-back buffer. You can move the view of the buffer after switching to copy mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>. In the copy mode you can move up and down using cursor keys or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd> or alternatively using other keys. The copy mode can be closed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>. For details see:

- [Linux: GNU/Screen Scroll Up and Down Look At Data](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/scroll-up-down-look-at-data-in-gnuscreen-using-pageup-pagedown-keys/)
- [How to scrollback in GNU SCREEN?](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/11/14/faq-how-to-scrollback-in-gnu-screen/)

Comment: You could pipe the output to a file.  Then you can view the output at any time by opening the file in a editor. I often do this to keep track of a long script or process, while I'm doing something else.